# What personal identification documents does the British Royal Family have?

Tags: united-kingdom, monarchy, identity-document, royal-family

What personal identification documents do members of the Royal Family have? Does the card allow all members of the Royal Family to travel any place with just that card?

Comment: We already got a question about [the personal identification documents of the Queen](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/4945/what-personal-identification-documents-does-the-british-queen-have), but it does not cover the rest of the royal family.

Comment: What do you mean by "Does the care allow"?

Comment: I meant card not care, sorry. My other question are the princess in the royal family allowed to make personal cell phone calls to people outside of the Royal family? Thanks

Comment: I meant Prince's such as Andrew.

Comment: I'm trying to find out for a friend if she is actually talking to Prince Andrew through Hangout. He keeps telling her because he is part of the Royal Family that this is the only way he can communicate with her, non verbal just the written word. He is telling her some special card will come to her that then lets him talk to her. This all sounds like a catfish to me. Any way to find out what is going to help, thanks for your help.

Comment: Anyone claiming to be a member of the BRF in a situation like that is automatically a scammer. They either want to be known as who they are, in which case the evidence will be overwhelming, or they want to be anonymous, in which case you will never know.

Answer (score 4):

The [Royal website](https://www.royal.uk/passports) partially covers this (emphasis mine)

> As a British passport is issued in the name of Her Majesty, it is unnecessary for The Queen to possess one. **All other members of the Royal Family, including The Duke of Edinburgh and The Prince of Wales, have passports.**

And [this article about drivers licenses says](https://www.express.co.uk/news/royal/1018826/Queen-Elizabeth-news-Why-does-the-Queen-not-need-a-driving-licence-Royal-Family)

> Queen Elizabeth has visited more than 100 countries during her reign, but she has not needed to provide any proof of identity once.
>
> This is a privilege for the reigning monarch only.

So it's safe to say that all other members of the family need a normal ID and/or license that any other UK citizen would need.

Comment: Of course, UK citizens don't actually have any obligatory ID.

Comment: @origimbo No, but they don't have an exemption either. So Prince Charles doesn't have to have a drivers license, but if he wants to drive a car he will need one to comply with the law. If/when he becomes King he will become exempt from that