# Does a sitting US president require a passport to travel internationally?

Tags: united-states, president, borders, identity-document

The same question related to Queen Elizabeth II has been [asked](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/4945/13161) and [answered](https://www.royal.uk/passports) on this site: The Queen does not require a passport to travel internationally.

I am interested in learning **whether this is also true of a US president who is in office at that time**.

Comment: Hi Politics.SE!  I'm active on other stacks but this is my first question on this site.  Please let me know if and how I can improve my question.

Comment: Your links are about Queen Elizabeth II, not [Queen Anne](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anne,_Queen_of_Great_Britain).

Comment: @GrahamNye - Thanks for your comment, but I'm not sure I understand it. Is there something I should know about Queen Anne?

Comment: As described at the top of my link Queen Anne was the last Queen of England.

Comment: @GrahamNye - I think you're suggesting that I change "Queen of England" to "Queen of the United Kingdom".  Is that correct?

Comment: It would be better to change to [Queen Elizabeth II](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_II). She is not just Queen of the United Kingdom, as set out in the sidebar of the link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the President of the United States has a passport, according to the [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/morning-mix/wp/2015/03/30/australian-official-accidentally-released-passport-info-for-obama-30-other-world-leaders-report-says/).

However, it is not the kind of ordinary passport that most Americans would get, but rather, it is a Diplomatic Passport.

Comment: While it is true that he has a passport I don't think it ever gets checked when he travels internationally.

Comment: There is a difference between *unlikelihood of being checked* and *not having to carry papers.*

Comment: Possibly relevant link on political passports: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwih9MXEg5LwAhXRGs0KHUmNAxQQFjABegQIBhAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fkr.usembassy.gov%2Fu-s-citizen-services%2Fpassports%2Fofficialdiplomatic-passport%2F&usg=AOvVaw2svZuay0nyfGa0GNKcVSnE

Comment: @o.m. there's also a difference between _having a passport_ and _having to have a passport._  If the US (or any country really) chose to adopt a similar position to that of the UK and declare that the head of state did not require and was not to be issued a passport, no country that wished to receive an official visit from that head of state would let the lack of a passport get in the way.

Answer (score 2):

> Does a sitting US president require a passport to travel internationally?

The other answer is correct to say that the president *has* a passport, and in fact the president probably has at least two because he would retain his ordinary passport when the diplomatic passport was issued.  But the question is whether the president *requires* a passport to travel internationally, and the answer to that is *no.*  Any  country that wants to receive the US president, or any other head of state, will do that whether the person has a passport or not.